# Why "php x.php &" leads to a STOPPED background process

Tags: linux, php, ubuntu-12.04

x.php:

```
<?php
sleep(15);
?>
```

console:

```
$ php x.php &
[1] 5742
[1]+  Stopped                 x.php
```

**Result:** a "STOPPED" process - it's there forever until I send a `TERM` and then `CONT` signal.

**What I need instead:** the process to finish and quit after 15 seconds, so I don't see it in `top` or `htop`.

System: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in VirtualBox; php-fpm

Comment: Actually it is not about "how to code something", but about "how to run my script in background", which looks more like a question related to "power users", as stated in the website's Tour. Re: what you are trying to do - that's described in the "What I need instead" paragraph.

Comment: Is there more to `X.php`, or did you just forget to close your PHP tag in the example?

Comment: Nothing else in x.php file (it's allowed and recommended to omit closing tag). Fixed my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  It would be easier to just run `sleep 15` instead of `php`.

Comment: @KevinPanko The PHP script is just a minimal example used for simplified testing and posting to this website - it was used in replacement of the real workhorse-script.

Comment: @KevinPanko , questioning why I use PHP instead of something else doesn't help with my original question. Instead it just changes direction of the discussion, unfortunately.

Comment: There may be a simpler/better way to do what you want to do.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 4):

Using `strace` I see that the program is getting a signal `SIGTTOU` which means the process was in the background and attempted to write to the terminal, or in this case, change one of its modes.

```
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_GINFO or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGTTOU {si_signo=SIGTTOU, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
--- stopped by SIGTTOU ---
```

To get around this, set the input to null:

```
$ php x.php < /dev/null &
```

The question is the same as this one: [PHP script won't run in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194755/php-script-wont-run-in-the-background)